# How to declare and deal with float type in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have angular App which interact with backend required to send `json` like this:

```
{"prop": 654646f}
```

I have two problems, I can't find the type float in `typescript` also if the value have quoted in default `JSON` it isn't accepted. So how to remove quotes from certain property value in `JSON`?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There is no `float` type in Typescript. All numbers are from the type `number`.

If you want to cast an `string` as number you can simply do it with the `+` operator. Example:

```
myNumberString: string = "25";
myNumber: number = +myNumberString;
```

Answer (score 19):

A cleaner look is to do

```
myNumber: number = Number(myNumberString);
```

Comment: Even cleaner is `myNumber = Number(myNumberString);` Since the type can be inferred.